# Creating Time Dimension in BusinessObjects

Tags: business-objects

Is it possible to create a time dimension with values inside the BusinessObjects, and if yes, please explain how?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to create time dimension. I wanted to create the time dim in the databse. However, the user that communicates with database has only read rights. Therefore, I was wondering if it would be possible to create the time dim directly in BO. Is that possible at all?

Comment: Should be possible with a Derived Table.  Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://ginoscheppers.wordpress.com) site by Gino Scheppers. Gino created a generic time dimension framework that can be implemented in a BusinessObjects universe, aptly named the *Ultimate Generic Date/Time Framework*.

If you're using a recent version of BusinessObjects and Web Intelligence as a frontend, the `TimeDim()` function may also be of use to you. From the user guide:

> The `TimeDim` time dimension allows you to build a time axis from a date
>   type universe object. `TimeDim` returns the data for the dates given as
>   the first parameter over the time periods given as the second
>   parameter.